IntelliJ PhpStorm - HTTP Client - How to use OS environment variable in request?
Using the HTTP Client direct in PhpStorm I have the need to make requests with actual OS environment variables - without using the http-client.env.json or http-client.private.env.json.
A sample os-env-var.http could be:
### sample GET request
GET https://internal.testserver.de/api/v1/profile/{{USERNAME}}/

On Windows USERNAME should be using the OS environment variable %USERNAME% or $env:username.
Are there any solutions for this?

From what I see -- will be supported in the next 2024.3 version (you can try the EAP build now). $env.ENV_VAR as per the ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-66621
